# Update data from one Map to another

Tags: rust, functional-programming

How can I do the following.
Suppose I have the following document created

```
{ 
    "_id": "12345",
    "email": "julio@gmail.com",
    "password": "julio123",
    "created": "2021-08-17",
    "status": "0"
}
```

and now through the created document I wish to have a new document like the following one.

```
{ 
    "email": "julio@gmail.com",
    "password": "julio123",
    "status": "1"
}
```

I don't know if what I did is correct, but I know that more code is missing.

```
#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use serde_json::{Map, json};
    #[test]
    fn prueba() {
        let mut user = Map::new();
        user.insert("id".to_string(), json!("12345"));
        user.insert("email".to_string(), json!("juan@gmail.com"));
        user.insert("password".to_string(), json!("juan123"));
        user.insert("created".to_string(), json!("2021-08-17"));
        user.insert("status".to_string(), json!("0"));
        println!("user: {:#?}", user);

        let user2 = user.into_iter().fold(Map::new(), |mut user_map, (key, val)| {
            user_map.insert(key.clone(), val.clone());
            user_map
        });

        println!("user2: {:#?}", user2);
    }
}
```

I'm just learning to use functional programming, I need help to get the best possible result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you seem to want to achieve is to filter and update some fields, creating a new object as a result.
Here is how you might do that:

```rust
let user2 = user
    .into_iter()
    .filter_map(|(k, v)| match k.as_str() {
        "email" => Some((k, v)),
        "password" => Some((k, v)),
        "status" => Some((k, json!("1"))),
        _ => None,
    })
    .collect::<Map<_, _>>();
```

Comment: Thank you very much for answering, sorry for delaying me in accepting your answer because I was doing some housework.

Comment: I have one last question, with what function can I insert a new attribute on the map? Could you answer me? please.

Comment: @Daniel Take a look at `Map::insert` (https://docs.rs/serde_json/1.0.66/serde_json/struct.Map.html#method.insert) for that. By the way, docs.rs hosts documentation generated by rustdoc on every crate on crates.io (or you can view all the documentation locally via `cargo doc`, see https://doc.rust-lang.org/rustdoc/index.html)